# NoMethodError (undefined method `fetch' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable

Issue is with broadcasting data through a web socket using ActionCable. The error seems to suggest its coming from the create method.

**Error Message**

```
 Rendered weight/_weight.html.erb (1.1ms)
 [ActionCable] Broadcasting to weight: "<div class=\"row\">\n  <div class=\"col-md-8 well\">\n    <p>12.0 kg</p>\n    <small>less than a minute</small>\n  </div>\n</div>"
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 25ms (Views: 7.4ms | ActiveRecord: 10.6ms)



NoMethodError (undefined method `fetch' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/weight_controller.rb:7:in `create'
Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.text.erb
Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.text.erb
Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.text.erb (0.8ms)
Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb
Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.9ms)
Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb
Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb (1.1ms)
Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.text.erb (25.0ms)
```

**Create method from controller.rb**

```
def create
   @weight = Weight.new(weight_params)
   @weight.user_id = current_user.id
    if @weight.save
        ActionCable.server.broadcast "weight", render(partial: 'weight/weight', object: @weight)

    else
        flash[:danger] = "New Weight was not added!"
        redirect_to current_user
    end
end

private

def weight_params
    params.require(:weights).permit(:weight)
end
```

I just cant work out what is returned as nil. The fact that the info is correct in what it is broadcasting to weight is correct suggests it has saves it correctly to the database. Can't think what else it is performing the 'fetch' method on.

Pretty sure the web socket is set up correctly. See below.

**config/application.rb :**

```
config.action_cable.mount_path = '/cable'
```

**config/routes.rb :**

```
mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
```

**weight_channel.rb :**

```
def subscribed
  stream_from "weight"
end
```

**weight.coffee :**

```
 received: (data) -> 
    $("#messages").prepend(data)
```

Comment: With line is line 7 of the `weight_controller.rb` file? and where (if) are you calling `fetch`? (in the view? in the model? in a validation called by `save`)?

Comment: Line 7 is 5th line in the extract above. I am not using fetch anywhere.

Comment: For debugging purposes, consider separating the `render` from the `broadcast` and placing the in two different lines. i.e.: `tmp = render(partial: 'weight/weight', object: @weight)` new line `ActionCable.server.broadcast "weight", tmp`... let us know which line (which method call) raises the new error.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, its coming this line of code ActionCable.server.broadcast "weight", @tmp - does that mean its an issue with the way the web socket has been set up?

Comment: You should have full stack trace in your logs (not just one line `app/controllers/weight_controller.rb:7:in `create'`) - could you paste it in your question?

Comment: could you post the code in your `config/cable.yml` file? (strip any passwords or secrets before you do so) ... you can edit your own question with the data.

Comment: @will , these errors can occur due to a missing, misnamed or invalid `config/cable.yml` file. This is why I'm asking you to post the file's content (if you have one).

Comment: @Myst the error seemed to be that I didn't have one. Have just added it in and its working now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was raised due to a missing `config/cable.yml` file.

The solution was to use a `config/cable.yml` with the required setting for the application. i.e.:

```
# Action Cable uses Redis by default to administer connections, channels, and sending/receiving messages over the WebSocket.
production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

staging:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

test:
  adapter: async
```

The resolution appears in the question's comments.